# Get content without the content of child elements

Tags: jquery

how can i get the "li" text without the "span" content?

HTML

```
<ul class="texts">
    <li>jimbo <span>Add text</span></li>
    <hr />
    <li>mary jane <span>Add text</span></li>
    <hr />
    <li>bill clinton <span>Add text</span></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.texts li span',function() {    
        var current_content =  $("#addReply textarea").val();
        var chosen_content = $(this).parent("li").html();
        $("#addReply textarea").val(current_content + "\n" + chosen_content)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the contents without **just** the span that was clicked, you can use [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) and [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) (and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) rather than `html`, because it returns the text of all of the entries in the set you call it on [unlike `html`, which only returns the HTM of the first entry in the set]):

```
var chosen_content = $(this).parent("li").contents().not(this).text();
```

Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.texts li span', function() {
  var current_content = $("#addReply textarea").val();
  var chosen_content = $(this).parent("li").contents().not(this).text();
  $("#addReply textarea").val(current_content + "\n" + chosen_content)
});
```

```html
<ul class="texts">
  <li>jimbo <span>Add text</span>
  </li>
  <hr />
  <li>mary jane <span>Add text</span>
  </li>
  <hr />
  <li>bill clinton <span>Add text</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="addReply">
  <textarea cols=40 rows=5></textarea>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the parent element, then removing the `span`, and finally get the content:

```
var foo = $(this).parent("li").clone();
foo.find('span').remove();
var content = foo.text();
```